# Moving a stacked bar that that worked in Bokeh 0.9 to Bokeh 0.11

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh, stacked-chart

I'm updating all my systems from Bokeh 0.9 to Bokeh 0.11, and have one chart that I can't seem to get to work anymore.

I start with a DataFrame like this:

```
Out[75]: 
         First  Second  Third  Fourth  Fifth
Red         27      22     33      20      9
Blue        10      27     18      31     14
Magenta     32      10     11       8     10
Yellow       8       6     14      13     15
Green        9       5      6       6      2
```

And I would produce a nice chart with colors names along the axis, 5 stacked bars in the same order as the legend, which would give the ranks.  For example, this is the output for a stacked bar with 10 ranks and 10 categories that we generated in 0.9.0:

[Stacked Bar with 10 categories and 10 ranks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5uar.png)

I used to do this by just:

```
plot = Bar(dataframe, list_of_color_names, title="stack of 5 categorical ranked in order from first to last", stacked=True, legend="top_right", ylabel="count", width=600, height=600)
```

Where "list_of_colors_names" was just a list generated from the index of the DataFrame, but this doesn't work anymore. I realize that 0.11 drops "stacked=True" and and now we use "stack", but I still can't seem to get it to work.

The examples on the Bokeh website are for simpler bar charts and when I apply that model to my DataFrame I get a variety of errors, such as "'NoneType' object is not iterable", but I'm clearly just missing the larger picture about how this type of stacked bar works in 0.11. There are a few other Bokeh stacked bar discussions here but they are either for an earlier version of Bokeh (my code worked in 0.9), or seemed to be a different case. What's the most best way to do this kind of stacked bar now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it is the only way of doing it, but the stacked bar chart in Bokeh 0.11 works if you put **all the data in a column**, rather than in a matrix. You then need to provide the matrix row and column indexes in corresponding dataframe columns, called `nr` and `rank` in the example code below. These are referred when calling the Bar method, where "stack" shall refer to the columns in your matrix example.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, show

all_data={
'nr':  [1,2,3,4,5,
        1,2,3,4,5,
        1,2,3,4,5,
        1,2,3,4,5,
        1,2,3,4,5],
'rank':['First','First','First','First','First',
       'Second','Second','Second','Second','Second',
       'Third','Third','Third','Third','Third',
       'Fourth','Fourth','Fourth','Fourth','Fourth',
       'Fifth','Fifth','Fifth','Fifth','Fifth'],
'data':[27,10,32,8,9,
        22,27,10,6,5,
        33,18,11,14,6,
        20,31,8,16,6,
        9,14,10,15,2]
      }
df=pd.DataFrame(all_data)

p=Bar(df,label='nr',values='data',stack='rank',legend='top_right')
show(p)
```

A comment: The standard Bar chart palette only has six colors, as shown in your 10 rank example. I use the code snippet below, adapted from others, to generate as many distinct colors as needed for the bar chart. It uses a matplotlib colormap colormap as input.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

colormap =cm.get_cmap("jet")
different_colors=10
color_mapping=colormap(np.linspace(0,1,different_colors),1,True)
bokeh_palette=["#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b) for r, g, b in color_mapping[:,0:3]]

p=Bar(df,label='nr',values='data',stack='rank',legend='top_right',palette=bokeh_palette)
show(p)
```

Here is a good page discussing how to choose [matplotlib colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html).

Comment: Thanks, Anadyn. That worked great. I guess I just need to get the data in columns from now on. It was nice to be able to just produce the chart from the matrix without any further change, but I admit it is not difficult to just stack the data and reset the index.

Comment: Glad it worked out! I agree that the matrix formulation is more intuitive. But when the data is acquired by querying a database, as in my case, the data comes in the column formulation straight away and there is no need to sort it in a matrix. The code then actually gets shorter.